# Is it possible to get specified values in the stat variable of proc means output?

Tags: sas, mean, summary

So I am working on generating summary dataset. I need to print only the values of N,MIN,MEDIAN,MAX,STD. It will be convenient for me to get the result as the statistics in a single variable stat. But if I use proc means without specifying the stats after output statement, I just get the default stats. Is there any way of doing this? This is what I tried.

```
PROC MEANS DATA=sashelp.class NWAY N MIN MAX MEDIAN STD;
 CLASS name;
 VAR height weight;
 OUTPUT OUT=output (DROP=_type_ _freq_ RENAME=(_stat_=stat)) ;
RUN;
```

It only shows the default stats.
Anyway, I can specify the stats in output option, but I want the output like from the code I have provided.
Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Generate them in "wide" format and then transpose to "tall" if you want.

```
PROC SUMMARY DATA=sashelp.class NWAY N MIN MAX MEDIAN STD;
 CLASS name;
 VAR height weight;
 OUTPUT OUT=wide n= min= max= median= std= /autoname ;
RUN;

proc transpose data=wide(drop=_type_ _freq_) out=tall ;
  by name ;
run;

data tall ;
  set tall ;
  length Stat $32 ;
  stat = scan(_name_,-1,'_');
  _name_=substr(_name_,1,length(_name_)-length(stat)-1);
run;

proc transpose data=tall out=want(drop=_name_);
  by name stat notsorted;
  id _name_;
  var col1 ;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    Name       Stat      Height    Weight

  1    Alfred     N           1.0        1.0
  2    Alfred     Min        69.0      112.5
  3    Alfred     Max        69.0      112.5
  4    Alfred     Median     69.0      112.5
  5    Alfred     StdDev       .          .
  6    Alice      N           1.0        1.0
  7    Alice      Min        56.5       84.0
  8    Alice      Max        56.5       84.0
  9    Alice      Median     56.5       84.0
 10    Alice      StdDev       .          .
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want. I just wanted to know if there was any way of minimizing the code.